# add method in jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am validating my form via jquery validation plugin. I am facing one problem and I have one query. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61pptcb3/1/)

1. Problem: I have add custom validation using addmethod. It is working fine but relevant message is not displaying.
2. query: I have to check that username entered by user is exist or not. I am getting response after ajax call in form of JSON. ex

   {"username":"exist"}

I make another customer validation method.

```
 $.validator.addMethod("specialChar", function(value, element){      
  return response.username!="exist"
 },"{0} already exist");
```

My Question is how to fire this validation after ajax success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myform').validate({
        onfocusout:function(element){           
            this.element(element)
        },
        rules:{
            username:{
                required:true,
                specialChar:true
            }
        },

        messages:{
            **"username": {
                required: "bhai ye required hai",
                specialChar: "bhai ye special bhe mat daal"

            }**


        }
    })
```

bold is the change in code

and updated fiddle as well : http://jsfiddle.net/61pptcb3/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better of using the [special `remote` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method). It allows you to set up an ajax request to validate a element. It does require you to make a small change to your server setup, but it makes the rest a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.validator.addMethod("specialChar", function (value, element, params) {
    var patt = new RegExp(/[^A-z]/g);
    return !patt.test(value);
});


$('#myform').validate({
    onfocusout: function (element) {
        this.element(element)
    },
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            specialChar: true
        }
    }
});

$.extend($.validator.messages, {
    required: "My own text.",
    specialChar: "special charactor not allow"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add and show an ajax-loader, while user enters the username. When the jQuery ajax call returns hide the ajax-loader icon and show the message if user does not exist.

To provide a [callback to jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) use:

```
jQuery.ajax(url, {complete: function(){}});
```

To [validate the element when the ajax returns use](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element):

```
$("#myform").validate().element("#i1");
```

To put it together do this:

```
$.ajax(url, {complete: function(data){
     // truigger validation on ajax complete
     $("#myform").validate().element("#i1");
}});
```

Comment: if we use $("#myform").validate().element("#i1"). which validation will be fired

Comment: @amit, it should fire all the validations added on that element